# issue on pushing refs on Git repository

Tags: git, push

I faced some errors when push my code to a repository.

```
Enumerating objects: 8497, done.
Counting objects: 100% (8497/8497), done.
Delta compression using up to 12 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2168/2168), done.
Writing objects: 100% (8497/8497), 11.66 MiB | 238.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 8497 (delta 4941), reused 7457 (delta 4542), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (4941/4941), done.
To https://github.com/promewizard/OSMDASHBOARD.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (refusing to allow an OAuth App to create or update workflow `.github/workflows/android.yml` without `workflow` scope)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/promewizard/OSMDASHBOARD.git'
```

I tried to change android.yml and ensure that the OAuth App has the required workflow scope to create or update workflows.
But i couldn't not get correct answers.
How can I fix this error?

Comment: how did you try to ensure that the OAuth App has the required workflow scope? did you give the ssh key or the credentials you use the essential permissions for workflows?